# React useState hook is not working as expected inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

**Disclaimer:** Please don't mark this as duplicate. I've seen similar questions with answers. But none of them is working for me. I'm just learning React.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically infinite scrolling. So that when a user scrolls to the end of the page, more data will load.

I've used `scroll` `eventListener` to achieve this. And it is working.

But I'm facing problems with the state of the variables.

**First**, I've changed the `loading` state to **true**. Then fetch data and set the state to **false**.

**Second**, when scrolling to the end of the page occurs, I again change the `loading` state to **true**. Add **1** with `pageNo`. Then again fetch data and set the `loading` state to **false**.

**The problems are:**

1. `loading` state somehow remains **true**.
2. Changing the `pageNo` state is not working. `pageNo` always remains to **1**.
3. And actually none of the states are working as expected.

**My goal: (Sequential)**

1. Set `loading` to `true`.
2. Fetch 10 posts from API after component initialization.
3. Set `loading` to `false`.
4. After the user scrolls end of the page, add 1 with `pageNo`.
5. Repeat Step 1 to Step 3 until all posts loaded.
6. After getting an empty response from API set `allPostsLoaded` to `true`.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried adding all the states into dependencyList array of `useEffect` hook. But then an infinite loop occurs.

I've also tried adding only `pageNo` and `loading` state to the array, but same infinite loop occurs.

**Source:**

```
import React, { lazy, useState } from 'react';
import { PostSection } from './Home.styles';
import { BlogPost } from '../../models/BlogPost';
import { PostService } from '../../services/PostService';

const defaultPosts: BlogPost[] = [{
    Id: 'asdfg',
    Content: 'Hi, this is demo content',
    Title: 'Demo title',
    sections: [],
    subTitle: '',
    ReadTime: 1,
    CreatedDate: new Date()
}];

const defaultPageNo = 1;
const PostCardComponent = lazy(() => import('./../PostCard/PostCard'));
const postService = new PostService();

const Home = (props: any) => {
    const [posts, setPosts]: [BlogPost[], (posts: BlogPost[]) => void] = useState(defaultPosts);
    const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(defaultPageNo);
    const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [allPostsLoaded, setAllPostsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [featuredPost, setFeaturedPost]: [BlogPost, (featuredPost: BlogPost) => void] = useState(defaultPosts[0]);

    async function getPosts() {
        return await postService.getPosts(pageSize, pageNo);
    }

    async function getFeaturedPost() {
        return await postService.getFeaturedPost();
    }

    function handleScroll(event: any) {
        console.log('loading ' + loading);
        console.log('allPostsLoaded ' + allPostsLoaded);
        var target = event.target.scrollingElement;
        if (!loading && !allPostsLoaded && target.scrollTop + target.clientHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
            setLoading(true);
            setPageNo(pageNo => pageNo + 1);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                getPosts()
                    .then(response => {
                        const newPosts = response.data.data;
                        setLoading(false);
                        if (newPosts.length) {
                            const temp = [ ...posts ];
                            newPosts.forEach(post => !temp.map(m => m.Id).includes(post.Id) ? temp.push(post) : null);
                            setPosts(temp);
                        } else {
                            setAllPostsLoaded(true);
                        }
                    })
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function init() {
        setLoading(true);
        Promise.all([getFeaturedPost(), getPosts()])
            .then(
                responses => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setFeaturedPost(responses[0].data.data);
                    setPosts(responses[1].data.data);
                }
            );
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        init();
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
      }, []
    );
    
    return (
        <PostSection className="px-3 py-5 p-md-5">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="item mb-5">
                    {posts.map(post => (
                        <PostCardComponent
                            key={post.Id}
                            Title={post.Title}
                            intro={post.Content}
                            Id={post.Id}
                            ReadTime={post.ReadTime}
                            CreatedDate={post.CreatedDate}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </PostSection>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: `UseEffect` triggers on a change to its dependencies, so yes, adding `pageNo` to your deps will cause an infinite loop if you change `pageNo` in your `useEffect` block, which you do. Same with `loading`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your whole problem, but I suspect that you need to move `handleScroll`'s definition outside of the `useEffect` block, as it may become undefined once the block falls out of scope.

Comment: @samuei, the whole point is I'm trying to update `pageNo` and `loading` property. And none of them is being changed. `pageNo` always remains 1 and `loading` always remains true.

Comment: Please try moving your function definitions outside the `useEffect` block.

Comment: You create the callback for `useEffect` on first render and your `pageNo` is baked into the closure. Therefore it never changes. But -excuse my frankness- your component code is quite a convoluted mess. You may want to clear that up. As the old saying goes: "If you can't get it clear you won't get it right." (probably Conficius, 400 A.D.)

Comment: Updated question with the latest source.
@samuei , I've moved the function definitions outside the useEffect block. Still interacting with default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used more effects to handle the change of `pageNo`, `loader` and `allPostsLoaded` state worked for me.

**Updated Source:**

```
import React, { lazy, useState } from 'react';
import { Guid } from "guid-typescript";
import { PostSection } from './Home.styles';
import { BlogPost } from '../../models/BlogPost';
import { PostService } from '../../services/PostService';
import { Skeleton } from 'antd';

const defaultPosts: BlogPost[] = [{
    Id: '456858568568568',
    Content: 'Hi, this is demo content. There could have been much more content.',
    Title: 'This is a demo title',
    sections: [],
    subTitle: '',
    ReadTime: 1,
    CreatedDate: new Date()
}];
const defaultPageNo = 1;
const defaultPageSize = 10;
const PostCardComponent = lazy(() => import('./../PostCard/PostCard'));
const postService = new PostService();

const Home: React.FC<any> = props => {
    const [posts, setPosts]: [BlogPost[], (posts: BlogPost[]) => void] = useState(defaultPosts);
    const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(defaultPageNo);
    const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(defaultPageSize);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [allPostsLoaded, setAllPostsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [featuredPost, setFeaturedPost]: [BlogPost, (featuredPost: BlogPost) => void] = useState(defaultPosts[0]);

    function getNewGuid() {
        return Guid.create().toString();
    }

    async function getPosts() {
        return await postService.getPosts(pageSize, pageNo);
    }

    async function getFeaturedPost() {
        return await postService.getFeaturedPost();
    }

    function init() {
        setLoading(true);
        Promise.all([getFeaturedPost(), getPosts()])
            .then(
                responses => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setFeaturedPost(responses[0].data.data);
                    setPosts(responses[1].data.data);
                }
            );
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        init();
        return;
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (allPostsLoaded || loading) return;

        function handleScroll(event: any) {
            var target = event.target.scrollingElement;
            if (!loading && !allPostsLoaded && target.scrollTop + target.clientHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
                setPageNo(pageNo => pageNo+1);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
      }, [loading, allPostsLoaded]
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (pageNo > 1) {
            setLoading(true);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                getPosts()
                    .then(response => {
                        const newPosts = response.data.data;
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            setLoading(false);
                            if (newPosts.length) {
                                const temp = [ ...posts ];
                                newPosts.forEach(post => !temp.map(m => m.Id).includes(post.Id) ? temp.push(post) : null);
                                setPosts(temp);
                            } else {
                                setAllPostsLoaded(true);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    })
            }, 1000);
        }
      }, [pageNo]
    );

    return (
        <PostSection className="px-3 py-5 p-md-5">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="item mb-5">
                    {posts.map(post => (
                        <PostCardComponent
                            key={post.Id}
                            Title={post.Title}
                            intro={post.Content}
                            Id={post.Id}
                            ReadTime={post.ReadTime}
                            CreatedDate={post.CreatedDate}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </PostSection>
    );
};

export default Home;
```