# How to use InfiniteScroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, infinite-scroll

My idea is : when I click into the page, the page will send a axios request for the top 30 data and show them in the InfoCard. After that, when I scroll to the end of the page it will send a new axios request for the next 30 data and show them in the InfoCard.

I watched this tutorial and tried it myself but I still not sure how it works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZKUirTtxcg

```
//TestScreen3.js

function TestScreen3() {

  const [topNdata, setTopNdata] = useState(30)
  const [skipNdata, setSkipNdata] = useState(0)

  const { loading, ScenicSpot, hasMore } = RequestTest(topNdata, skipNdata)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="Scenic Spots" />
        <CityList />
        {ScenicSpot.map((infoCard) => (<InfoCard key={infoCard.ID} Name={infoCard.Name} Description={infoCard.Description} Picture={infoCard.Picture.PictureUrl1} />))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestScreen3;
```

```
//RequestTest.js

export default function RequestTest(topNdata, skipNdata) {
    const [ScenicSpot, setScenicSpot] = useState([])
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        setScenicSpot([])
    }, [topNdata])

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Tourism/ScenicSpot',
            params: { $top: topNdata, $skip: skipNdata },
        }).then(res => {
            setScenicSpot(res.data)
            setHasMore(res.data.length > 0)
            setLoading(false)
        }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
    }, [topNdata, skipNdata])

    return { loading, ScenicSpot, hasMore }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it will seem like a different thing.

But you will found a way for infinite scroll here at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739664/react-usestate-hook-is-not-working-as-expected-inside-useeffect-hook).

Read the question and my answer to this question.

Though I was using axios from my API, you will get the idea from there.